# Is there a single word that I can use to refer to different TeX-based formats or engines?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, luatex, tex-core

I am writing an article on the TeX, pfdTeX, XeTex and LuaTeX engines and the LaTeX, pfdLaTeX, XeLaTex and LuaLaTeX formats. I find it necessary in some parts of my article to refer to the above-mentioned engines as a family of document typesetting engines and to the above-mentioned formats as a family of typesetting formats. Are there standard terminologies that refer the engines and the formats as families of engines and formats?

Comment: In the unix/linux/... world it's common to see `*nix`. Maybe `*\TeX` will work for you.

Comment: Just `TeX` for all formats should be sufficient and only clearify if you mean a specific format; That's why there is just TeX.SE  and not additional  `LuaTeX.SE` or `LaTeX.SE` sites

Comment: @ChristianHupfer as you are German I'm surprised you didn't suggest the word anytexbasedenginesuchaspdftexorluatexorxetex (welcome back to the site:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Too short then...

Comment: I am very grateful for the above suggestions. I'll adopt and modify the suggestion given by @EthanBolker.  I'll  use `*\TeX` as the name for the family of TeX engines and `*\LaTeX` as the name for the family of LaTeX  formats.